# Taylor Series Loop for sin(x) in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, taylor-series

I am working on a Python program in Jupyter Notebook that outputs the sum of a Taylor Series of sin(x) and e^x and compares them to the math module's output for a school assignment. The e^x portion seems to work fine, the output sum is close to the module calculation. However, the sin(x) portion is completely off and I'm not sure why. I'm sure it has to be in my series_sum calculation setup, but I've been staring at it for hours with no luck. Please help if you can, I greatly appreciate it!

```
import math

def taylor(func,x,terms=10):
    series_sum=0
    if func=='sin':
        for i in range(terms):
            if(i==10):
                break;
            series_sum=series_sum+(math.pow(-1,i)*math.pow(x,2*i+1))/math.factorial(2*i+1)
            math_value=math.sin(x)
        print("The Taylor series approx is",series_sum,"and the math function value is",math_value)
    else:
        for i in range(terms):
            if(i==10):
                break;
            series_sum=series_sum+math.pow(x,i)/math.factorial(i)
            math_value=math.exp(x)
        print("The Taylor series approx is",series_sum,"and the math function value is",math_value)
func=input("Which function to use sin/exp:")
x=int(input("Enter the value of x: "))
terms=int(input("Enter number of terms: "))
if x>50:
    raise Exception("x should NOT exceed 50")
elif x<-50:
    raise Exception("x should NOT be less than -50")
elif terms>100:
    raise Exception("terms should NOT exceed 100")
elif terms<1:
    raise Exception("terms should NOT be less than 1")
else:
    taylor(func,x,terms)
```

Comment: Whitespace is readability's good friend, and good code must be readable. Staring at your code won't help. Have you tried [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it? Pick a test case that fails, solve it step-by-step on paper, then step through your code in a [debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953). Once you have identified a line where your code does something unexpected, trace backwards to get to the source of the error.

Comment: If you [plot your calculated value and the expected value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcNHi.png), you'll see that your function only ever gets bad at large values of `x`. This is because the Taylor series expansion gets less accurate at those higher values of `x`. If you want to fix this, you will need to increase the number of terms in the Taylor series, or as Andrej said, modulo `x` by `2pi` to get `0 <= x < 2*pi` where the 10-term Taylor series expansion is accurate enough. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVhIQ.png)

Comment: Note that your `if i == 10: break` prevents you from actually having more than 11 terms

Answer (score 2):

Sinus is defined in the range from `0` to `2*PI` so to get more precise result just do `x = x % (2 * math.pi)` before computing sin Taylor series:

```py
import math

def sin_taylor(x, terms=10):
    series_sum = 0
    math_value = math.sin(x)
    x = x % (2 * math.pi)
    for i in range(terms):
        series_sum = series_sum + (
            math.pow(-1, i) * math.pow(x, 2 * i + 1) / math.factorial(2 * i + 1)
        )

    print(
        "The Taylor series approx is",
        series_sum,
        "and the math function value is",
        math_value,
    )


sin_taylor(62.3, 10)
```

Prints:

```
The Taylor series approx is -0.5072969037125172 and the math function value is -0.5071313157685321
```